# useEffect with dependency called infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have an alert that I want to hide in a timeout function after an item is added/removed from a list.

Instead of cleaning up the timeout function, useEffect ends up in a loop.

```
function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
  });
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [isEditing, setISEditing] = useState(false);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    active: false,
    type: "",
  });

  const addToList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setAlert({ active: true, type: "success" });
    let newItem = { id: new Date().getTime().toString(), name: item };
    e.preventDefault();
    setList([...list, newItem]);
  };

  const removeFromList = (id) => {
    setAlert({ active: true, type: "danger" });
    setList(list.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert({ active: false, type: "" });
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [alert.active]);
```

I have a similar example below, but there useEffect did not end up in a loop, although I change the state in useEffect.
What exactly is the difference between the two?

```
const SingleColor = ({ rgb, weight, index }) => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
  const hex = rgbToHex(...rgb);

 useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(false);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [alert]);

  return (
    <article
      className={`color ${index > 10 && "color-light"}`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: hex }}
      onClick={() => {
        setAlert(true);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(hex);
      }}
    >
      <p className="percent-value">{weight}%</p>
      <p className="color-value">{hex}</p>
      {alert && <p className="alert">Copied to clipboard!</p>}
    </article>
  );
};

export default SingleColor;
```

Comment: Your effect has a dependency on the state that it itself changes, therefore there is this infinite loop. You probably don't need `useEffect` at all, just do `setTimeout` in `removeFromList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `alert.active` dependency you are telling to retrigger  the `useEffect` each time `alert.active` changes. And Inside the `useEffect` you are setting up a new value for `alert.active` therefore creating an infinite loop.

You should rather call the timeout directly at the end of the addToList or remove from list function. If you want you can isolate it in a separate function

```
const cancelTimeout = () => {
   setTimeout(() => setAlert({ active: false, type: "" }), 3000)
}
```

and call `cancelTimeout` it at the end of `AddToList` and `removeFromList`